# Mouse Click event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a picture on background in a picture box and i have another picturebox small one above the first.now second picbox is not visible its hidden i want that if user clicks and holds mouse button small picturebox displays and as soon he removes hold i.e releases click picturebox vanishes.

now i thought of doing in click event i should make small one visiable but how to check if click is pressed not released?

sorry if i messed up with question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the mouse down event:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

}
```

there you can set the focus on whatever you want

and when you release:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `MouseDown` event in that case?

Comment: that worked for single but what if i have multiple buttons above picture 1 ? i am using picture of keyboard to simulate click

Comment: @Afnan: not sure if I understand your requirement. What is it you are trying to do? If you have multiple buttons above picture 1, which are hidden and you want to unhide then on MouseDown then this should work. Or you only want to unhide where the user clicks down first?

Comment: I have to unhide the hidden small picture box at the place where user clicks.

Comment: take an example of keyboard i have one big picture of keyboard and i have to show different image on the key clicled

Comment: Use the X and Y properties of the MouseEventArgs to determine where the user clicked the mouse.  Then look through each of your hidden images and figure out if that mouse click occurred over top on of them.